# Select2 not working in Jquery-Steps wizard plugin

Tags: asp.net

Please help with the script function on how to make select2 plugin work in wizard jquery template it is not firing and i'm using the search box, when it clicked it jams.Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

$('.class').select2(); AFTER $('#form').steps();
This has helped me thanks but..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#form").steps({
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
        {
            // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
            if (currentIndex > newIndex)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Forbid suppressing "Warning" step if the user is to young
            if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age").val()) < 18)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var form = $(this);

            // Clean up if user went backward before
            if (currentIndex < newIndex)
            {
                // To remove error styles
                $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
                $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
            }
            // Disable validation on fields that are disabled or hidden.
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";

            // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
            return form.valid();
        },
        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
        {
            // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
            if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age").val()) >= 18)
            {
                $(this).steps("next");
            }

            // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
            if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
            {
                $(this).steps("previous");
            }
        },
        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            var form = $(this);

            // Disable validation on fields that are disabled.
            // At this point it's recommended to do an overall check (mean ignoring only disabled fields)
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";

            // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            var form = $(this);

            // Submit form input
            form.submit();
        }
    }).validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element)
        {
            element.before(error);
        },
        rules: {
            confirm: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    });

   //IMPORTANT 
    var form =$("#form");
    form.find("#personel_id").select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
    });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation substantiating your answer.